A record label released a 45 RPM in 1966 that is troublesome (saturated, at least). What faults can have been done during recording session?
I am listening to Ka'orm Tmey (ក្អមថ្មី) from Ros Sereysothea & Va Sovy, a 45 RPM record of 1966 or 1967 according to its record number 45.66064.
The song is nice, but the recording is: saturated at least, I've haven't the knowledge to describe the troubles it has. But between 1'00 to 1'45, it has plenty.
I don't think the uploader of that song over the Internet is really responsible of this. They are crackling: he is uploading from a record, by playing it, yes.
I don't hear it, neither, like a record being too old and degraded at the moment the uploading to the Internet is done.
For me, Angkor Disques, the record label who released it, recorded it wrongly
(it's odd, because others recordings they did are perfect, like Pen Ran for reference 45.66044)
Am I right?
Can you figure what the producer might have done during recording session?
Use of weak material, maybe. Misplacing microphones? (it would be strange)?

I think you're right it's not degraded at the point of digitising, there could be a few things going on.
The comparison piece you posted sounds pretty pristine, I wouldn't be surprised if this was from a master tape or similar, there's no record crackle or similar going on. The Ka'orm Tmey recording is from a 45rpm record, which could be very variable in quality, degrade substantially with dirt and plays etc (for cheaper prints). and a cheap record player will play them back very crunchy and saturated like this recording.
It could be that the uploader digitised the recording with reasonable gain levels and good recording practice but a bad needle (or a record player that doesn't have much in the way of good needles available to buy) can sound pretty similar to this recording. ie the sound extracted from the medium before digitising was already compromised. They may have a cheap record player with a digital out, which would probably be a bit of a bargain basement thing, or maybe have even recorded a speaker out from a nicer player, which would add all sorts of other deviations from the original sound. That said with a decent soundcard and if the record in question was good quality you would expect decent representation.
So thats not ideal, not a fault of the digitiser but simply the equipment reading the disc is not at all high fidelity, and all of this will be captured in the digital file.
But on top of that it does sound as though the vocals, especially the female vocal, is saturated on the recording. It can be hard to tell sometimes where this comes from. It may just be that as it is fairly loud and in a particular register the record player is struggling to cleanly represent this part (for the reasons above). But it could also be on the recording itself. These records were not recorded with the best available gear of the time, and good quality gear was very expensive in the 60's. As this was almost certainly recorded live they may have got a situation where they couldn't get the gain they wanted to tape, and opted for louder vs too quiet.
To elaborate on that some older mic pre's were stepped, sometimes in quite large intervals, I had some very nice BBC mic pre's that were like this. It was ALWAYS the case that one setting was too quiet, and one too loud. In software it is easy enough to record clean and then boost, but if this was a quick 60's recording session they may well have been mixing while recording and opted for pushing the vocals a bit too far in order to get it loud enough and not have to work out later how to boost that track during a separate mix session (such a session may not have been budgeted for).
Also, mic's have a limit to the sound pressure level (SPL) they can work with, modern mics are very hard to challenge unless on a drum kit or similar but in a locale of limited gear in the 60's it may just be that the mic they chose to use was reaching it's SPL limit. Her voice is quite strong and piercing, it may just have been that they didn't have another option, or liked the sound of that mic enough to accept a bit of distortion, favouring how it pierces the mix.
The rest of the track seems well recorded and balanced so no reason to suspect the recording engineer was lacking.
We'll never know the exact reason, recording in those days was MORE of a science in music industry hotspots like the US and Europe, in that the recording engineers were also audio engineers and often had good knowledge of how the gear they used worked internally. But comparitively potentially LESS of a science in areas that didn't get access to the best gear of the current era, they had to just make do with what they had and get the best out of it that they could.
I think it's probably a combination of all the above, digitised from a lossy medium maybe with a less than perfect capture device and with the original recording being a little bit pushed in various areas out of necessity, leading to it sounding a bit 'hot'. You'd almost certainly get a better result if you could find original master tapes and digitise that, only then would you know how saturated the vocals were in the original mix, and it would probably be a bit less and maybe just on the edge of 'clean enough'.
Worth noting, although this particular digitisation arguably ends up going too far lots of engineers love to try and recreate this fuzzy dreamlike sound and will seek out old gear that distorts like this. A bit LESS distortion than this and it would sound very evocative of a certain naive golden era of recording for some!
EDIT:
I came across a version of the recording that was not digitised from a record player, most likely from the original tapes, and we can see that the overall distortion level is indeed way less. So we can be sure the recognised distortion was from the particular playback/digital capture process on the originally posted recording. The female vocal is a bit hot still, and on the edge, but it is quite a lot better than the other digitisation, definitely more on the side of 'acceptable'.
It also has a bit less bass and this potentially means the digitiser of the originally posted version may have either captured eq changes (via the settings on their devices) or processed that version a bit, which also could have introduced a bit of distortion.




I'm impressed by your analysis. Thanks!

@MarcLeBihan see my edit, I found another version likely from the original master tape!

thanks again! I granted you a bounty : you're deserving it!

@MarcLeBihan thanks for the bounty! Glad I could be helpful!
